# Configure Kotlin Notification In Android Studio made rendering preview

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

[image: Configure Kotlin Notification]

I applied this notification without knowing what it does. Now UI is missing. It says "Some issues were found while trying to render this preview" while preview and when I run app, It shows a blank surface. How and Where can I configure this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find what the notification changes in the project.

when I apllied notificitaion , it adds `build.gradle:app` to this twice like below.

```
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:+'
```

Although I have already implemented this

```
'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
```

This leads rendering problem.